# How to combine request from external API and send it as a response in Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm hitting the Hacker news API [here](https://github.com/HackerNews/API) and want to get the details of each posts that I get through the JSON. I want to send this JSON to my React front-end.

This request is taking a long time. What do I need to do to send the response?

```
@app.route('/api/posts')    
def get_posts():
    r = requests.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/askstories.json?print=pretty')
    data = r.text
    jsonData = []
    for post in data:
        r = requests.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/'+post+'.json?print=pretty')
        r.text
        jsonData.append(r.text)
    jsonData = jsonify(jsonData)
    print jsonData  
    return jsonData
```

Comment: Is there a problem with what you're already doing? Your indentation seems a bit wonky, but otherwise what errors are you seeing?

Comment: The page is taking a very long time to load. Even now there isn't anything in the console as we speak.

Comment: Well, yeah, you have to wait for several other requests and responses to complete. Was this unexpected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're querying a json API and treating the response as text:

```
r = requests.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/askstories.json?print=pretty')
data = r.text
```

So, `r.text` would be a string "[1234,1235,1236]" and *not* a list of integers.

So when you iterate over that in your `for post in data` what you're doing is getting each character:

```
for post in data:
    print(post)
```

Would give you:

```
[
1
2
3
4
,
...etc
```

So your essentially querying the hacker news API for hundreds of invalid posts, instead of tens of actual ones.  You should be treating the `json` as json— by using the json features built into requests: `data = r.json()`

That will give you a list of numbers to iterate over— you'd also need to change the bad way you're concatenating your data to make your url string (use `.format`).

Answer (score 2):

`requests` has a `.json()` method that you should use to convert your JSON array string into a python list.

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: r = requests.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/askstories.json?print=pretty')

In [3]: jsonData = r.json()

In [4]: for data in jsonData[:5]:
   ...      print data
   ...:
12102489
12100796
12101060
12097110
12094366
```

As stated in the other answer, `for post in data:` is going to give you individual characters from the HTTP response. In other words, think about what would `for post in "abc":` give you.

> The page is taking a very long time to load

That's because you are running a new query against all those individual characters.